# How to name the localization file for customized (renamed) Info.plist?

Tags: ios, xcode

Goal: create some localized strings and use them in **Info.plist**.

Standard Solution: create **InfoPlist.strings** and enable localization for it.

Fact: My Info.plist is actually named "*Abc Xyz-Info.plist*" (there is a space between Abc and Xyz).  And I tried to create "*Abc Xyz-InfoPlist.strings*" and "*AbcXyz-InfoPlist.strings*", neither of them works.

Question: How to make the localization work for my renamed Info.plist?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the conventional naming works: **InfoPlist.strings**.  It doesn't matter how you name your **Info.plist** file, as long as the **xcodeproj** config is correct (*Project* -> *Build Settings* -> *Packaging* -> *Info.plist File*, the value is set to the correct path or your Info.plist file).

Steps:

1. Create a new file: iOS -> Resource -> Strings File -> InfoPlist.strings;
2. Xcode should automatically add corresponding metadata to your project.pbxproj;
3. Show Utilities and enable localization for it;
4. Add content to it.

Tested OK with Xcode 7.1.1(7B1005).

Answer (score 0):

Do not rename `InfoPlist.strings` and enable localization for it. Xcode will take care of the rest. There is usually one created by default in all Xcode projects, did you remove it ?

Comment: Thanks.  But we renamed it, and want to keep the renaming due to some reason.

Comment: Well you can't... The system works this way and will be looking for this file when attempting to localize.

Comment: My friend told me that he managed to make it work even with file renamed, but luckily he doesn't have space inside.